# UV Texture not rendering

Tags: rendering, uv

I know this is such a simple issue, but I've tried the solutions stated in related posts to no avail. The texture is attached to a material and it's unwrapped (I think) but it's still not showing up in the render (just black).

I've attached a screenshot and the blend file.

Thank you very much!!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_3PfctyK8jYldFLU5SY1dYWkk/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: please, to benefit all present and future users, use provided tools to share .blend files: after uploading the .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you can append the provided link editing your question, thanks!

Comment: I deleted the black "material" and made sure the "005" was associated with the mesh. Still no good!

Answer (score 1):

The template had no light! All I had to do was make the mesh "emission" and it worked!

Thank you for the help!